# Can't found magento 1.9.1.0 Admin Panel > mobile?

Tags: ios, magento, mobile, web

I have install magento 1.9.1.0 , but on backend i can't find mobile button.

why magento 1.9.1.0 Remove Admin Panel > mobile  ? And if i want to make my webapps in the future , how i can't do without mobile ?Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the `Mage_XmlConnect` module is enabled. I believe [it's disabled by default on Magento CE 1.9.1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-later-release-notes#ee114-11410-mobile) (equivalent to EE 1.14.1). To check, open `app/etc/modules/Mage_XmlConnect.xml` and look at the `<active></active>` tag. If it says `false`, change it to `true`.

Comment: Great! Please consider marking this answer as accepted so that others will know what worked for you.

Comment: That Mage_XmlConnect is added/downloaded in Magento Connect Manager or default one?